# what is the Accuracy of distanceTo(Location dest) method in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

What I am trying to achieve is  to do a certain task what distance between two location is less than 10 m using distanceTo method to calculate distance.

But I am not sure that will the distanceTo method will give me about 80% of its accuracy, and if not what shall i use to calculate exact distance

Now my question is, how does distanceTo method calculates distance between 2 location and by what accuracy ?

Comment: after consulting the `android.location.Location` class sources, whats unclear?

Comment: accuracy of distanceTo

Comment: so sis you see `computeDistanceAndBearing` method?

Comment: can you please give me the link ?

Comment: and for your information I have calculated distance , but I am unsure of its accuracy

Comment: go to `<android_sdk_root>/sources` folder, what do you see there?

Comment: i can see android-23

Comment: so see `android-23/android/location/Location.java` source file and ^F `distanceTo`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163639/discussion-between-dhami-ji-and-pskink).